# Norming the sum of estimated probabilities to 1

Tags: r, probability

I use an ANN to estimate win probabilities in basketball. Therefore, both teams of a given matchup have win probabilities, which should logically add up to 100%. 
Unfortunately, the sum of the probabilities for a matchup is everywhere between 95% and 105%. 
Right now I am using Excel to work around the issue and divide the probability with the sum of both probabilities to always get a sum of 100%. 
I would like to do this in R, but don't know how, as the sum of probabilities is never the same for any pair of probabilities. 
Any help is appreciated!

An example of two matchups:

```
Example A:
0.7177853
0.3038550
sum = 102.2

Example B:
0.4401672
0.5872775
sum = 102.7
```

For Example A it should convert to roughly 70.3% and 29.7% after the calculations are done..

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c(0.7177853, 0.3038550)


recalc <- function(x, y) {
  values <- sum(x, y)
  mult <- 1 / values
  newx <- x * mult
  newy <- y * mult
  return(c(newx, newy))
}

recalc(0.7177853, 0.3038550)

[1] 0.7025812 0.2974188
```

If you data is stored in a dataframe, we can `Vectorize` the function:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(0.7177853, 0.7677853, 0.5177853),
  y = c(0.3038550, 0.438550, 0.7038550)
)

newfunc <- Vectorize(recalc)
newfunc(x = df$x, y = df$y)

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.7025812 0.6364609 0.4238443
[2,] 0.2974188 0.3635391 0.5761557
```

You want this I guess.

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but I have to add up probabilities for more than 1000 games.. I would like to have one function to do this for all the games. Thanks!

Comment: Well you did not provide example data. Are your probalities in a list, a dataframe or where? Do that and i will help you